# Which distro supports the first raspberry pi? pi1

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, pi-1

piCore from tinycorelinux supports rpi 1, but it seems to be missing some drivers that i need, and also, their downloads are not signed or shasummed. Though the official raspberry pi debian stretch is also not a signed download.

Are there distros for the raspberry pi 1 rev A that are small, with up to date repositories, and are signed downloads? The raspbian stretch lite does not work for the rpi 1A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspbian Stretch (all 3 versions) works on ALL model Pi, have published checksums, and is maintained - at least until superseded by Buster (and for some time after).

NOTE There is no such thing as a Pi 1.

The initial releases were Raspberry Pi Model A & Model B.
There was a Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2 and later releases increased memory to 512MB

I have Raspbian Stretch 9.9 with Desktop running on my *Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2*

Comment: It doesn't, i have a pi1 with rpi stretch-lite and it doesn't boot up. The tinycorelinux piCore does. I've checked the checksums as well just in case it was a bad download

Comment: i was following the nomenclature suggested by the available tags, and the zeitgeist of the forums

Answer (score 0):

Every distro that supports Raspberry Pi Zero also supports the original Raspberry Pi as it uses the same SoC.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the raspbian-stretch version instead of the lite version, and rpi boots now.

Thanks!

Comment: Please upvote the correct answer and accept it with the tick icon next to the answer. There is no need to post a "thanks" as an answer.

Comment: So the lite version didn't boot? Thats strange.

Comment: The actual answer is to not use the lite version

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using the Pi A, [this one]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#/media/File:Raspberry_Pi_-_Model_A.jpg) the original Pi model A?  Perhaps this is a bug in the Raspbian Lite distribution.  According to Wikipedia, the exact same BCM2835 is used in the Pi Zero and Pi Zero W.  I can test that .